# Swift JSON error Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10b2cba88) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10b2cd1a8)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I get this error but I don't get why since im not using NSArrays
this is my code

```
let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                as! [String: Any]
```

print(todo)

I've use others APIS and they work fine and I don't think the problem is my API since it works correctly on C# 
can any one help please

Comment: change `[String: Any]` by `[Any]`

Comment: Thanks it work. But why did it work with my others apis?

Comment: simply because other APIs returned different results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously `responseData` contain an array and not a dictionary, try this:

```
let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as! [[String: Any]]
```

You can cast a JSON result of the API call to `[String: Any]` if the root object of the result is a JSON object, e.g.:

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}
```

In this particular case the API returns an array of objects, not an object, something like this:

```
[
    {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
    },
    {
    "name":"Milan",
    "age":29,
    "cars":[ "Mercedes" ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I wasn't award of the difference between an array and an object. Now I get it, thank you